# Android: minification obfuscating dynamically accessed classes

Tags: android, apk, minify, android-proguard

I am using [Samsung's Motion library](http://developer.samsung.com/resources/motion) to create a pedometer for Samsung phones. When I create an APK without minification in the gradle configuration file the system works. However when I try to apply minification before releasing to the store,

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
    }
```

I got errors claiming the some libraries (e.g. `android.hardware.motion`) do not exist. 
I have checked and:

- android.hardware.motion is not a standard library (probably existing only in Samsung phones?) in [android.hardware](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/package-summary.html)
- these classes are accesses dynamically (maybe because non standard?), e.g. `Class.forName("android.hardware.scontext.SContextManager");`

If I remove the line 
    minifyEnabled true
I got no error, so it must be the code obfuscation.

I have tried to add to my proguard rules file statements such as

```
-keep class android.hardware.** { *; }
-keep class com.samsung.android.sdk.** { *; }
```

but this does not seem to work.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to disable proguard and check release .apk?

Comment: I inserted: `-dontoptimize
-dontshrink
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose` but it did not help

Comment: If you are using gradle (that is recommended) you just need to remove line starting with `proguardFiles` (`android.buildTypes.release` section).

Comment: I use gradle. Excluding the line `android { buildTypes { proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' ` did not help

Comment: I have just updated. It is the minification. Not sure of why though and what happens if I remove it

Comment: minifyEnabled is a flag that tells ProGuard whether or not to run (if set to true ProGuard will run, minify, optimize and obfuscate your APK)

Comment: Thanks. This is really useful. I have changed the question after some investigations. I need to find the right form to avoid minifcation of the classes needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing classes are indeed only available on the actual device.
In order to let ProGuard process your application, you will have to include the following configuration:

```
-dontwarn com.samsung.android.sdk.motion.**
-dontnote com.samsung.android.sdk.motion.**
```

This will ignore the warnings and notes originating from the samsung sdk.

Comment: That is correct although per se insufficient. However I marked it correct because you put me on the right track. The correct solution is to have:

`-dontwarn com.samsung.android.**
-dontnote com.samsung.android.**

-keep class com.samsung.** { *; }
-keep class android.hardware.** { *; }`

Comment: I hardly doubt that all the mentioned rules are necessary. Especially `-keep class android.hardware.** { *; }` is meaningless as this package is installed on the device and thus not considered by ProGuard. I tested the sample project from the Samsung SDK and my rules were sufficient to build it successfully.

Comment: You are right. Except that samsung adds to the android.hardware package and hence what happened was that the new part was obfuscated. Any smaller subset did not work for me